# Kill ring bash shortcuts on Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, kill-ring

in Visual Studio Code (for mac) it doesn't seem to work the kill ring shortcuts on the bash terminal. I mean things like kill to right with ^K and to left ^U etc. However ^A does move the caret to the beginning and ^L does clean the screen, etc

I noticed that when I do it in the bottom bar it says `(^K) was pressed. Waiting for second key chord` but I find no way to bound the key stroke to kill left or to find anything useful in the Keyboard Shortcuts.

There a couple of kill-ring extensions but they don't seem to work or apply only to text fields within the vscode ui (not the terminal).

Any suggestion is welcome even if it is a bit unorthodox.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit of time, but the answer cam actgually in the own docks: to skip the chords in the terminal this setting is necessary at the settings.json:

`"terminal.integrated.allowChords": false`

Then all the key chord combinations will be handled directly by the terminal, including the kill ring commands.
See [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration).